# Disappearing button - after click

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to have a button (say A) in `sidebarPanel` such that after using it another button (say B) will be activated (by `renderUI`), but the button A will disappear. How can I do this

Here my naive solution. I do not know how to avoid referring button status to itself:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(

   ui = fluidPage(
      uiOutput("answer"),
      uiOutput("part2")
      ),

   server = function(input, output) {

      output$answer <- renderUI({
         if(input$continue == 0){
            checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "firstQ", label = "First question", choices = c("Ans. A" = "a", "Ans. B" = "b"))
            actionButton("continue", "Continue")}
      })

      output$part2 <- renderUI({
         if(input$kontynuuj > 0)
            actionButton("newButton", "New button")
      })

   }
))
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that `conditionalPanel` in your `ui` is what you need to use here. It will let you set a condition that determines if part of the UI is shown or not.

In the code below I moved the `checkboxGroupInput` and the first `actionButton` to the ui, and left the second `actionButton` as a `renderUI`. `conditionalPanel` will work either way.

Each `conditionalPanel` evaluates the "Continue" button, the first displays before it has been pressed, the second afterwards.

**It is important to note** that the condition must be written in javascript, not R. See `?conditionalPanel` for the details.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(             
     conditionalPanel(condition="input.continue==0",
          checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "firstQ", label = "First question", 
              choices = c("Ans. A" = "a", "Ans. B" = "b")), 
          actionButton("continue", "Continue")   
      ),

      conditionalPanel(condition="input.continue>0",
          uiOutput("part2")
      )
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$part2 <- renderUI({
        actionButton("newButton", "New button")
    })

  }
))
```